# Azure linked services with data factory custom activity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

Can't able to create linked services using Azure data factory (ADF),
I have read/write permission for linked services at ADF level.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

LinkedServiceResource storageLinkedService = new 
LinkedServiceResource(
new AzureStorageLinkedService
{
ConnectionString = new 
SecureString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + 
storageAccount + ";AccountKey=" + storageKey)
}
);
client.LinkedServices.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, 
dataFactoryName, storageLinkedServiceName, storageLinkedService);
```

BTW I used both client credential as well as user credential

```
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, 
authenticationKey);
var cc = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
```

### Error Response for using Client credential:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.ErrorResponseException: 
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.LinkedServicesOperations.
<CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__6.MoveNext() --- End of stack 
trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

### Error Response for using User credential:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:  Response status code does not 
indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). ---> 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: 
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The 
request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or 
client_assertion'.\r\nTrace ID: 2264d637-8786-4a40-96d4-
5d27b0670300\r\nCorrelation ID: fec688c8-bb92-49c2-86d3-
1e091181fe10\r\nTimestamp: 2017-11-29 05:30:23Z","error_codes":
[70002],"timestamp":"2017-11-29 05:30:23Z","trace_id":"2264d637-8786-
4a40-96d4-5d27b0670300","correlation_id":"fec688c8-bb92-49c2-86d3-
1e091181fe10"}: Unknown error
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: unable to create linked service using .net custom activity in Azure data factory

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to your exception, it seems that you use the resource owner flow from a a web client. A confidential client, such as a web App client, **cannot use** direct user credentials.

You would need to invoke it as a public client (native client app), not as a confidential client (web app/API). Please refer to this [document](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) for more about how to use ADAL,especially the **Constraints & Limitations** section

> No web sites/confidential clients
>   This is not an ADAL limitation, but an AAD setting. You can only use those flows from a native client. A confidential client, such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials.

**To access resources in your subscription, you need to [assign role to the registried App.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role)**

Please have a try to use the following to get TokenCredentials, The following is the demo code to create inked services. It works correctly on my side. We also could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net).

```
 private static async Task<string> GetToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
        {
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
            var tokenResponse = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential); 
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
        }



        var token = GetToken(_tenantId, _clientId, _screctKey).Result;
        TokenCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
        DataFactoryManagementClient client = new 
        DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
        DataFactoryManagementClient client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
        LinkedServiceResource storageLinkedService = new LinkedServiceResource(new AzureStorageLinkedService{
                     ConnectionString = new SecureString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + storageAccount + ";AccountKey=" + storageKey)});

       var result =client.LinkedServices.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup, factoryName, storageLinkedServiceName, storageLinkedService).Result;
```

[image]