# Programmatically delete datasets by name from Data Factory using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, azure, sdk, azure-data-factory

3 questions on Data Factory and the .NET SDK:

1) Is it possible to programmatically delete datasets from a Data Factory via the .NET SDK? I would ideally like to be able to pass the name of a dataset to delete and have it handle that. I've looked through the docs and can't seem to find any clear method.

2) When creating a dataset or pipeline, how can I test the response to see if it was successful.

3) When creating a dataset, is it possible to check the provisioning state and wait until it's been provisioned before creating a pipeline, since datasets must be created before the associated pipeline?

Comment: `Is it possible to programmatically delete datasets from a Data Factory via the .NET SDK?` If you are using Data Factory V2 (Preview) - please have a try to use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory/0.4.0-preview), If you are using the Data Factory V1,please have a try to use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories/)

Comment: You also could get some demo code from [github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/blob/master/Samples/ParameterizedPipelinesForAzureML/DeployDataFactory/DeployDataFactory/Program.cs) or another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546517/azure-linked-services-with-data-factory-custom-activity/47708289#47708289).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This is clearly possible with the methods Delete and DeleteAsync. They take the resource group name, data factory name and dataset name as parameter.

Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-data-factory-client and use the client object to call the method. It will look like client.datasets.Delete("ResourceGroupName","DataFactoryName","DatasetName")

2) If it doesnt return an error, then it was created successfully.

3) In my experience, Datasets are created almost instantly when using the .net sdk. The same goes for pipelines, have you had any troubles with it? I wouldnt even bother checking.

Comment: haven't had any issues creating pipelines or datasets. haven't been able to test for a response though. I want to be able to check the provisioning state and if it's been provisioned, then proceed on with creating the pipeline, since you can't create the pipeline until the dataset is created.